# Simplify boolean expression algorithm

Tags: algorithm, boolean-logic, boolean, boolean-expression

Anybody knows of an algorithm to simplify boolean expressions?

I remember the boolean algebra and Karnaught maps, but this is meant for digital hardware where EVERITHING is boolean. I would like something that takes into account that some sub-expressions are not boolean.

For example:

```
a == 1 && a == 3
```

this could be translated to a pure boolean expression:

```
a1 && a3
```

but this is expression is irreducible, while with a little bit of knowledge of arithmetics everibody can determine that the expression is just:

```
false
```

Some body knows some links?

Comment: What if `a` is declared as a volatile variable/field in languages/runtimes that allows those, and the value fluctuates between 1 and 3 on another thread? I'm not saying that is a good design, but in software, "always" and "never" are usually relative terms.

Comment: This is not a problem, the actual use is for a LINQ Provider and the actual values are the ones at the time the query is translated. If they query is executed again the simplification will be run again, with the updated values.

Comment: It's not possible in general. For example `a > 0 and b > 0 and n > 2 and a^n + b^n = c^n` is always false but it's not so easy to prove. That means you're stuck with ad-hoc simplifications and there's no clean answer to your question (since it'll depend on the nature of expressions you're likely to see).

Comment: You right, but since is just a simplification algorithm I'm ok with any algorithm that improve things, even if is not the best solution. The mein scenario is equality and disctinct operators for enum and reference types mainly. Integers with == >= > < <= != would be a nice to have.

Answer (score 10):

You might be interested in [K-maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) and the [Quine–McCluskey algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm).

I think SymPy is able to solve and simplify boolean expressions, looking at the source might be useful.

Answer (score 7):

Your particular example would be solved by an [SMT solver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_Modulo_Theories). (It'd determine that no setting of the variables could make the expression true; therefore it's always false. More-general simplification is out of scope for such solvers.) Showing that an expression is equivalent to `true` or `false` is of course NP-hard even without bringing arithmetic into the deal, so it's pretty cool that there's practical software for even this much. Depending on how much arithmetic knowledge is in scope, the problem [may be undecidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_%28logic%29#Some_undecidable_theories).

Answer (score 6):

There are two parts to this problem, logical simplification and representation simplification.

For logical simplification, Quine-McCluskey. For simplification of the representation, recursively extract terms using the distribution identity (0&1|0&2) == 0&(1|2).

I detailed the process [here](http://blog.clamav.net/2014/03/programmatic-boolean-simplification-and.html). That gives the explanation using only & and |, but it can be modified to include all boolean operators.

Answer (score 3):

Is the number of possible distinct values finite and known?  If so you could convert each expression into a boolean expression.  For instance if a has 3 distinct values then you could have variables `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` where `a1` being true means that `a == 1`, etc.  Once you did that you could rely on the Quine-McCluskey algorithm (which is probably better for larger examples than Karnaugh maps).  Here is some [Java code](http://en.literateprograms.org/Quine-McCluskey_algorithm_%28Java%29) for Quine-McCluskey.

I can't speak to whether this design would actually simplify things or make them more complicated, but you might want to consider it at least.

Comment: exactly!, that's what I mean but like this the algorithm will have no idea that, in my example, a1 && a3 is actually false. since a can't be 1 and 3 at the same time. I think what I need is to bind values to variables and find contradictions in the Karnaught minterms.

Answer (score 2):

First shot using Google found this paper:

http://hopper.unco.edu/KARNAUGH/Algorithm.html

Of course, that does not deal with non-boolean subexpressions. But this latter part in its general form is really hard, since there is definitely no algorithm to check if an arbitrary arithmetic expression is true, false or whatever. What you are asking for goes deeply into the field of [compiler optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_optimization).

Comment: I was reading the paper before, but I also found it quite undetailed and no code provided.

Answer (score -1):

This is hard man. The algorithm in the simplest way that I found was match every output combination with each input each combination. But that's the basic algorithm, didn't solve every expression.

If all output (q1,q2,q3,q4) is same with for i.e input A combination then the result of simplification will be A.

If not, you will try another variabel / input dependency.