# Boolean function simplifier?

Tags: boolean-logic

```
x = (a & b & d) | ~(a | ~b | c) | (~c & ~d & a) | (c & d)

~ = not
& = and
| = or
```

How do I simplify a function like this, with what should I start?
I've tried some simplifying programs but I don't understand them.

Comment: Is this homework or are you trying to solve a "real world" problem?

Comment: i am trying to save the world ok

Comment: Write out a truth table and then treat it like a [Karnaugh Map](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Comment: ok ive done that 2 years ago, will try, but is there any way to test if ive done it right? any programs

Comment: [Logic Friday](http://sontrak.com) is good is good for this kind of thing, assuming you know what you're doing (caveat: Windows only).

Comment: bad u guys give me minuses on post i just want help so rude

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(a+and+b+and+d)+or+not(a+or+not+b+or+c)+or+(not+c+and+not+d+and+a)+or+(c+and+d)&t=crmtb01) is good for getting the various variations that are possible but doesn't really explain how it got from a to b.

Comment: yeah i use wolfram alpha alot for other thigns but i dont understand what it outputs to me there, i dont know which one of the simplified forms is the one that i need

Comment: I think your question is perfectly legitimate, and was clear to me.

Comment: See [Simplify boolean expression algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311099/simplify-boolean-expression-algorithm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write out a truth table for the variables involved and the eventual output.

Then, for each of the rows in the truth table that turn out to be true, you write a logic equation based upon the variables' states to reproduce that logic "one", usually an AND function of the appropriate inputs and inverse inputs.

Say only 3 of the rows have a true or logic one output.
That would mean you'd have three logic equations.
You would complete the job by connecting those three equations together with OR operators.

By looking at the truth table, you might be able to notice that the output of the logical true lines do not depend on all of the variables. This is one way of simplifying the expression.

Solving an equation similar to the one you put above
(a & b & d) | (~a | b | ~c) | (~c & ~d & a) | (c & d)

I get the following result

x = 1 except for one case, i.,e., (a b c d) = (1 0 1 0), in which case it is zero.
Thus x = ~( a & ~b & c & ~d) or x = ~a | b | ~c | d

How to do this?
To make it easier to do this, you can rewrite your equation as

```
 x = A | B | C | D, where

 A =  (a &  b & d)
 B = (~a | b | ~c)
 C =  ~c & ~d & a
 D =   c &  d
```

variable B = 1 for all but two sets of inputs of (abcd) namely (1010) and (1011).

variable A = 1 for only only two input sets, which B already covers.

similarly with variable C.

Variable D = 1 for one of the two sets of inputs B didn't make = 1, namely (1011).

Thus x = 0 only when the inputs are exactly a=1, b=0, c=1, d=0, but we want to write it as an equation that is True (=1) when those inputs are given, so we write

```
 x = ~(a & ~b & c & ~d) or x = ~a | b | ~c | d
```

So that is one way of simplifying. I'll add a second technique in a separate answer.

sorry it took so long to spell it out, but perhaps others will find it useful.

The original equation of the OP is fairly simplified as is. The truth table has nearly equal T and F entries, and thus doesn't lend itself well to a demonstration of the technique. One could rewrite it as

```
 x = (a & b & d) | (~a & b & ~c) | (a & ~c & ~d) | (c & d)
```

which is fairly compact but could be written slightly differently combining the 1st and last terms and the middle two terms:
x = ((a & b | c) & d) | ((~a & b | a & ~d) & ~c)
see 2nd proposed answer below for a further explanation

Comment: i found some old notes, will do something like this, thanks hot boi

Comment: The question is somewhat vague. You could also minimize the function using the [Quine-McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm), or "simplify" the function by rewriting it into a normal form such as [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form).