# How To simplify boolean equations

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

*Note that this is an example question to represent the sum of all similar questions, please don't answer only the question below, but the general problem with optimizing boolean expressions*

---

I have this boolean Equation:`[boolean equation] e.g. (!B && A) || A`

is there any better way for this?

Comment: You can use following sequence for better performance 
A || (!B && A)

Comment: This question is not about how to simplify that single equation but in general

Comment: Thats way I added comment not answer.

Comment: For the general case - use Karnaugh map.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplify boolean expression algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311099/simplify-boolean-expression-algorithm)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A boolean equation follows simple calculations rules, known as the [`Boolean Algebra`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

With those rules, you can simplify any boolean equation with hard work:

```
 Associativity of ∨ :         x ∨ ( y ∨ z ) = ( x ∨ y ) ∨ z 
 Associativity of ∧ :         x ∧ ( y ∧ z ) = ( x ∧ y ) ∧ z
 Commutativity of ∨ :                 x ∨ y = y ∨ x 
 Commutativity of ∧ :                 x ∧ y = y ∧ x 
 Distributivity of ∧ over ∨ : x ∧ ( y ∨ z ) = ( x ∧ y ) ∨ ( x ∧ z )
 Identity for ∨ :                     x ∨ 0 = x
 Identity for ∧ :                     x ∧ 1 = x 
 Annihilator for ∧ :                  x ∧ 0 = 0 

 The following laws hold in Boolean Algebra, but not in ordinary algebra:

 Annihilator for ∨ :                  x ∨ 1  = 1
 Idempotence of ∨ :                    x ∨ x = x 
 Idempotence of ∧ :                    x ∧ x = x  
 Absorption 1:                 x ∧ ( x ∨ y ) = x  
 Absorption 2:                 x ∨ ( x ∧ y ) = x 
 Distributivity of ∨ over ∧ : x ∨ ( y ∧ z ) = ( x ∨ y ) ∧ ( x ∨ z )

 Complementation 1 :                  x ∧ ¬x = 0
 Complementation 2 :                  x ∨ ¬x = 1
 Double negation :                     ¬(¬x) = x
 De Morgan 1 :                       ¬x ∧ ¬y = ¬(x ∨ y)
 De Morgan 2 :                       ¬x ∨ ¬y = ¬(x ∧ y)
```

Note that

- `∨` represents `OR` (`||`)
- `∧` represents `AND` (`&&`)
- `¬` represents `NOT` (`!`)
- `=` represents `EQUALS` (`==`)

But with more complexity of your equation, this done by hand is almost impossible. The first step to the completion is the [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).
It should look something like this:[image: Truth table]

You can create truth tables also online, for example with this [tool](http://wahrheitstabelle.daug.de/#/).

From the truth table, you can create a [KV-Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).
Those can look like this:

[image: KV-Map]

There also online tools to create KV-Maps (I recommend [this one](http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/%7Ethormae/lectures/ti1/code/karnaughmap/))).

How to fill in those maps according to your truth table is not the topic here.

How to get boolean equations from the KV-Map is also not the topic, but the recommended tool is calculating it for you: [image: calculation]

In conclusion for the problem: if you want to optimize your boolean equations, create a truth table with your equation: [image: Truth table]

Fill in a KV-Map:

[image: KV-Map]

and replace your equation with the calculated shortest way possible:
[image: Calculation]

---

Supplement: the equation calculated with the KV-Map is the shortest way possible. There are still some transformations you can do with the boolean algebra, but that will not make these equations look easier.